# Replace a column with a calcutated column using the same name in spark SQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pipeline

I read files from my datalake and load them in a dataframe
The datas loaded have some fields that are not the same type as in the source database, due to a cast problem in kafka ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420662/cast-numeric-fields-with-kafka-connect-and-table-whitelist))

So, i load datas from S3 with the wrong datatype (bunary) and i cast each column in another with an UDF function

Then, i rename the new columns to replace the olders, to keep the same structure in my source databases and destination databases

Steps :

Before :

```
myTable
|
+-- myField1 (binary)
+-- myField2 (binary)
+-- myField3 (binary)
```

Intermediary state 1 (cast with UDF function) :

```
myTable
|
+-- myField1 (binary)
+-- myField1_new (numeric)
+-- myField2 (binary)
+-- myField2_new (numeric)
+-- myField3 (binary)
+-- myField3_new (numeric)
```

Intermediary state 2 (drop old column) :

```
myTable
|
+-- myField1_new (numeric)
+-- myField2_new (numeric)
+-- myField3_new (numeric)
```

Final state (rename computed column):

```
myTable
|
+-- myField1 (numeric)
+-- myField1 (numeric)
+-- myField1 (numeric)
```

Here is the syntax i use :

```
spark.sql('select *,
            MyUDF(myfield1) myfield1_new,
            MyUDF(myfield2) myfield2_new,
            MyUDF(myfield3) myfield3_new
            from my_table')
.drop('myfield1').withColumnRenamed('myfield1_new', 'myfield1')
.drop('myfield2').withColumnRenamed('myfield2_new', 'myfield2')
.drop('myfield3').withColumnRenamed('myfield3_new', 'myfield3')
.show(1, False)
```

My problem is that the process is really really slow, because of 439 fields to compute in the real production table (439 !!!)

Is there a way to do it faster ? On the fly renaming or whatever ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you try `data = data.withColumn("myfield1", yourUdf('myfield1'))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503697/create-an-spark-udf-function-to-iterate-over-an-array-of-bytes-and-convert-it-to/53704741#53704741) thread to this question.

Extending that one as, suppose you have the `df` as

```
+--------------------+
|             myfield|
+--------------------+
|[00, 8F, 2B, 9C, 80]|
|    [52, F4, 92, 80]|
+--------------------+
```

**EDIT**: Since the format of the column `myfield` is `bytearray(b'\x00')`, the way of conversion is as follows (as pointed out by @Ftagn). Otherwise, if it is a list of strings, use the `commented return`.

```
def func(val):
    return int.from_bytes(val, byteorder='big', signed=False) / 1000000
    # return int("".join(val), 16)/1000000
func_udf = udf(lambda x: func(x), FloatType())
```

And to create the output, use

```
df = df.withColumn("myfield1", func_udf("myfield"))
```

This yields,

```
+--------------------+--------+
|             myfield|myfield1|
+--------------------+--------+
|[00, 8F, 2B, 9C, 80]|  2402.0|
|    [52, F4, 92, 80]| 1391.76|
+--------------------+--------+
```

Instead if you use,

```
df = df.withColumn("myfield", func_udf("myfield"))
```

you get,

```
+-------+
|myfield|
+-------+
| 2402.0|
|1391.76|
+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick !
Note that it works with `return int.from_bytes(val, byteorder='big', signed=False) / 1000000`
Not with `return int("".join(val), 16)/1000000` raise an exception for me
`  File "<ipython-input-12-6b453c3d12b6>", line 2, in func
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: ahh.. can you just say what is the output of `type(df1.select('myfield').collect()[0][0])`

Comment: bytearray(b'\x00')